# Java: Connect 4 Winning Diagonally

Tags: java

I made a Connect4 game recently and my Connect4 doesn't win the game when it's connected diagonally towards the right. And it only works for some combinations when it's connected diagonally to the left. Coordinates:- Top left: (0,0), Bottom left: (5,0), Top right: (0,6), Bottom right: (5,6). The Connect4 board is 6 by 7.

**Problem:** Connecting diagonally towards left works fine for only some combinations. But, none of the connections connected diagonally towards right work.

```
/** A method of winning diagonally towards the left side when playing connect 4 two player*/
/** Giving the new method with all the possible possibilities for a user to win diagonally-left */
public static void diagWinningLeft() {
    for (int x = 5; x > 2; x--) { // Checks to see if same colored pegs are lining diagonally to the left
        for (int y = 6; y > 3; y--) {
            if (board[x][y] == 1 && board[x - 1][y - 1] == 1 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 1 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[0]+" has connected four diagonally-left in a row in " +(countForRed)+ " turns!");
                b.drawLine(x,y,x-3,y-3);
            }
            if (board[x - 1][y - 1] == 1 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 1 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 1 && board[x - 4][y - 4] == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[0]+" has connected four diagonally-left in a row in " +(countForRed)+ " turns!");
                b.drawLine(x,y,x-3,y-3);
            }

            if (board[x][y] == 2 && board[x - 1][y - 1] == 2 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 2 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[1]+ " has connected four diagonally-left in a row in " +(countForYellow)+ " turns!");
                b.drawLine(x,y,x-3,y-3);
            }
        }
    }
}

/** Another method of winning diagonally towards the right side when playing connect 4 two player*/
/** Giving the new method with all the possible possibilities for a user to win diagonally-right*/
public static void diagWinningRight()  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) { // Check to see if same colored pegs are lining diagonally to the right
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (board[x][y] == 1 && board[x + 1][y + 1] == 1 && board[x + 2][y + 2] == 1 && board[x + 3][y + 3] == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[0]+" has connected four diagonally-right in a row in " +(countForRed)+ " turns!");
            }
            if (board[x][y] == 2 && board[x + 1][y + 1] == 2 && board[x + 2][y + 2] == 2 && board[x + 3][y + 3] == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[1]+" has connected four diagonally-right in a row in " +(countForYellow)+ " turns!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me for not directly answering the question, but this is stuff that will help you fix it and end up with better code and a better ability to write code in future.

Extracting the logic of your "if" condition into a separate method makes it easier to think about that logic on its own, and lets you test it independently of the rest of the program.

So instead of:

```
  if (board[x][y] == 1 && board[x - 1][y - 1] == 1 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 1 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 1) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)
  }
```

... use:

```
 if(isDiagonalLeft(x,y,1) { ... }
```

... and ...

```
 boolean isDiagonalLeft(int x, int y, int player) {
      return board[x][y] == player && 
             board[x - 1][y - 1] == player  && 
             board[x - 2][y - 2] == player  && 
             board[x - 3][y - 3] == player 
 }
```

Now you can run **unit tests** on isDiagonalLeft() to make sure it works. That is, a small program that sets up a board and *just* runs isDiagonalLeft() to make sure it gives the right answer in various circumstances. This feels like extra work, but most people who try it learn that it saves effort by catching bugs early.

What you've done is to somewhat separate the game logic from the presentation code (JOptionPane), so that the presentation code is not in the way when you just want to exercise the game logic. Later on in your programming studies you'll encounter ways to separate these even more, like the Model-View-Controller model.

Pulling the logic out like this also helps if you need to ask questions on Stack Overflow -- by separating the game logic from Swing, you open up the question to potential answerers who don't know anything about Swing.

And, you can re-use this method, once for each player, rather than copying the logic into two places as you have.

If it doesn't work, use the *debugger* in your IDE to step through it.

Now that you've done this, you can smarten up the method so that the computer does the decrementing instead of the programmer...

```
  boolean isDiagonalLeft(int x, int y, int player) {
       for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
           if(board[x-i][y-i] != player) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
  }
```

...and you can generalise it so that it covers both directions of diagonal:

```
  boolean isDiagonal(int x, int y, int player, boolean direction) {
       int dirUnit = direction ? -1 : 1;
       for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
           if(board[x-i][y + dirUnit] != player) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
  }
```

... so now you can re-use the method in 4 places; for each player and for each direction.

When you come across a situation where it doesn't work in your GUI, make a unit tests that sets up the board the way it is in the GUI, and runs `isDiagonal()` on it. If the test passes, you know the problem is somewhere else. If the test fails, you can work with a debugger and the method's code, to make it pass.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```js
//Winning diagonally towards left
public static void diagWinningLeft() {
    for (int x = 5; x > 2; x--) { // Checks to see if same colored pegs are lining diagonally to the left
        for (int y = 6; y > 2; y--) {
            if (board[x][y] == 1 && board[x - 1][y - 1] == 1 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 1 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[0]+" has connected four diagonally-left in a row in " +(countForRed)+ " turns!");
                b.drawLine(x,y,x-3,y-3);
            }
            if (board[x][y] == 2 && board[x - 1][y - 1] == 2 && board[x - 2][y - 2] == 2 && board[x - 3][y - 3] == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[1]+ " has connected four diagonally-left in a row in " +(countForYellow)+ " turns!");
                b.drawLine(x,y,x-3,y-3);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Winning diagonally towards right
public static void diagWinningRight()  {
    for (int x = 5; x > 2; x--) { // Check to see if same colored pegs are lining diagonally to the right
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            if (board[x][y] == 1 && board[x - 1][y + 1] == 1 && board[x - 2][y + 2] == 1 && board[x - 3][y + 3] == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[0]+" has connected four diagonally-right in a row in " +(countForRed)+ " turns!");
            }
            if (board[x][y] == 2 && board[x - 1][y + 1] == 2 && board[x - 2][y + 2] == 2 && board[x - 3][y + 3] == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerNames[1]+" has connected four diagonally-right in a row in " +(countForYellow)+ " turns!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with your code was that while checking towards right your coordinates(indices) continued to check for left direction(as there are 4 diagonals from a[x][y] viz. a[x-1][y-1], a[x+1][y+1] constituting diagonal in NW-SE direction(or left diagonal) and a[x-1][y+1], a[x+1][y-1] constituting diagonal in NE-SW direction(or right diagonal)).
Moreover your inner for loop didn't run to the limits.Hence, diagWinningLeft() didn't work at times..